# Check if value exists in any SQL table

Tags: sql

Is there a way to check if a value exists in any table or column within a schema, without knowing in advance where exactly?

The only thing I know is by doing a select with where clause by specifying the attribute column. Perhaps somehow with the schema data, or if the value is indexed?

Comment: short answer: you shouldn't do this. don't mix structure and data. (the information_schema allows you to use structural information as data, the inverse is not possible, and should not be. -  there may be some special database feature in some weird database that does this though. key-value stores might be what you're looking for, or some solr search stuff, but that has nothing to do with sql)

Comment: You should specify the RDBMS you're using

Comment: I use Mysql and Oracle

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do this, but it is not recommended. On one hand you will be blocking every table in the database with your "query" and on the other hand you need to perform [NumberOfTablesInSchema] X [NumberOfColumnsPerTable] queries to accomplish that.

What you need to do is:

- query the information_schema for all tables and save them in a variable
- loop over every table using a cursor (comparable to foreach loop)

  - query the information_schema for all columns in that table and save them in a variable
  - loop over every column using a cursor (comparable to foreach loop)
  - create a dynamic sql statement that queries table x for the existence of the value in column y
  - execute the statement and save the result to a table or print it (table x contains value in column y 5 times)

you can see that there is a considerable amount of work to perform in order to achieve this "functionality"